# RuntimeError: shape '[1, 1, 399194]' is invalid for input of size 798388

Tags: python, runtime-error, google-colaboratory

I am very new to python. I am recently looking to make a synthesized voice out of natural voice used tacotron.

The code is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CnjNDvQmFFypt9VeOdxU25u7HylNkuCe#scrollTo=JiuUJH_ANSmv).

I ran all stuff according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVqSEIr2PD4&ab_channel=CherryStudios).

When I reached on creating mels:

```
if generate_mels:
    create_mels()
```

It says:

> RuntimeError: shape '[1, 1, 399194]' is invalid for input of size 798388.

Comment: Kinda looks like a `numpy` error, try changing one of the 1s to 2 perhaps, so that `x * y * 399194` = `798388`.

Comment: We can't access your notebook--check your sharing settings